# Scrapy: How to schedule spider to run every hour?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that helps me with data collection from the web.
I need this spider automatically starts to work every hour.
I tried to use closed signal to yield a new request but it seems that it is not working after closed signal.

```
def __init__(self):
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

def spider_closed(self, reason):
    time.sleep(3600)
    link="http://www.google.com"
    request=Request(url=link, dont_filter=True,callback=self.parse_item)
    yield request
```

That would be great if somebody can help me on that

Comment: You didn't provide the code that you use to call the function. You also requesting an input `reason` that you are not using in the function.

Comment: according to scrapy [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed) `spider_closed()` method is used when spider is closed or completed its execution. If you want to run your spider periodically use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [aps](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Linux? Use `cron`. Or use a platform like scrapinghub, they have a free plan now.

Comment: hey ! @user2079550 im struck with this same issue, So can i know how exactly u added a scheduler for scrapy spider ..Thanks!